# Python POST to API requests issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, https, pytest

I've been working on making API tests with pytest on Python 3.10.10 and I have stumbled on an issue with a post request. Here is the code I currently have:

```
import requests as req

api = 'some api'
header = {
    'Apikey': 'some token',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

payload = {
    "title": "TItle",
    "description": "<p>DEscription</p>",
    "column_id": 12345,
    "lane_id": 1234
}

URL = api + '/cards'

card_id = 0

def test_get_card():
    x = req.get(
        URL,
        headers=header,
        params={'cards_id': 123456}
    )

    assert x.status_code == 200

def test_create_card():
    x = req.post(
        URL,
        headers=header,
        data=payload
    ).json()

    print(x)

    assert x.status_code == 200
```

The first test is a success!
The second doe returns 400 and `Please provide a column_id for the new card with reference CCR or have it copied from an existing card by using card_properties_to_copy.`

If I run the same request in `Insomnia` it returns 200. I can't figure out why it fails.

Any help would me much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps the requests library and insomnia are handling the serialisation of the payload differently. Have you tried using a string for column_id rather than an int?

Comment: Just tried it. The issue is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your feedback, here was the issue you were encountering. From the request docs [https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls][1]

> There are times that you may want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data will be posted directly.

So it seems your endpoint accepts JSON-ENCODED. In that case you'll want to `import json` and update your `test_create_card` function to the following.

```
def test_create_card():
    x = req.post(
        URL,
        headers=header,
        data=json.dumps(payload)
    ).json()

    print(x)

    assert x.status_code == 200
```

or as you discovered pass the payload using the json param (in versions >= 2.4.2) which will do the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, that will do the trick instead of formating the json to a string manually 

Answer (score 0):

So I found two solutions!

One:
If I modify the payload as:
`payload = "{\n    \"title\": \"TItle\",\n    \"description\": \"<p>DEscription</p>\",\n    \"column_id\": 10124,\n    \"lane_id\": 8629\n}"`

It goes through!

Two:
If I change in the request data=payload to json=payload that fixes the issue as well.